# Get everything before a specific node with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I got the following XML content

```
<root>
   <node1>Hi from node 1</node1>
   text not encapsulated in node
   <node2>Hi from node 2</node2>
   <node3>content....<node3/>
</root>
```

The question is : how to get all content before node3, even those not   encapsulated in a node using XPath version 1.0 or 2.0 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/root/node3/preceding-sibling::node()
```

will select all of the nodes, not just elements, preceding `node3` as siblings:

```
   <node1>Hi from node 1</node1>
   text not encapsulated in node
   <node2>Hi from node 2</node2>
```

If you really want the content of all previous sibling nodes, [see @DanielHaley's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57397568/290085), or use (also XPath 2.0):

```
/root/node3/preceding-sibling::node()/string()
```

yielding:

```
    Hi from node 1 
   text not encapsulated in node
    Hi from node 2
```

Use `normalize-space()` in place of `string()` to normalize whitespace:

```
 Hi from node 1 text not encapsulated in node Hi from node 2
```

Note that these return multiple strings (which may be concatenated in context) whereas Daniel Haley's XPath expression will directly return a single string, which may be more directly what you want.

Comment: Worked with me, Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Since you can use XPath 2.0, I'd use a combination of string-join() and normalize-space()...

```
string-join(//text()[following::node3]/normalize-space(),' ')
```

returns...

```
Hi from node 1 text not encapsulated in node Hi from node 2
```